# Making a class IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, class, ienumerable

I have the following classes

```
namespace TaxiResults.Model
{

public class SearchResult
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public SearchResultResult result { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResultResult
{
    public SearchResultOffer offer { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResultOffer
{
    public SearchResultOffer1[] offers { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResultOffer1
{
    public SearchResultAddress[] addresses { get; set; }
    public string chnl { get; set; }
    public string companyInfoId { get; set; }
    public string companyName { get; set; }
    public string bookingId { get; set; }
    public string tz { get; set; }
    public string pickupDateTime { get; set; }
    public string pickupDateTimeUTC { get; set; }
    public int routeDuration { get; set; }
    public int routeDistance { get; set; }
    public SearchResultPricedetail priceDetail { get; set; }
    public float tax { get; set; }
    public string services { get; set; }
    public int bagCount { get; set; }
    public int passengerCount { get; set; }
    public int productType { get; set; }
    public string resultset { get; set; }
    public string companyInfoId3cd { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResultPricedetail
{
    public SearchResultOriginalprice originalPrice { get; set; }
    public SearchResultFinalprice finalPrice { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResultOriginalprice
{
    public SearchResultAmount[] amounts { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResultAmount
{
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string priceExcludingTax { get; set; }
    public float priceExcludingTaxNumber { get; set; }
    public string priceTotal { get; set; }
    public float priceTotalNumber { get; set; }
    public float exchangeRate { get; set; }
    public string priceTax { get; set; }
    public float priceTaxNumber { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResultFinalprice
{
    public SearchResultAmount1[] amounts { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResultAmount1
{
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string priceExcludingTax { get; set; }
    public float priceExcludingTaxNumber { get; set; }
    public double priceTotal { get; set; }
    public float priceTotalNumber { get; set; }
    public float exchangeRate { get; set; }
    public string priceTax { get; set; }
    public float priceTaxNumber { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResultAddress
{
    public SearchResultLocation location { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public int type { get; set; }
}

public class SearchResultLocation
{
    public float lat { get; set; }
    public float lng { get; set; }
}

}
```

and I wanted to do a foreach loop on `Taxi.Model.SearchResult` to feed it into the model I am returning in my MVC view.

but I get the error:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Taxi.Model.SearchResult' because 'Taxi.Model.SearchResult' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

im new to c#.net can anyone tell me what I need to do to enable me to do a foreach please?

Thanks

Comment: [A Beginner's Tutorial on Implementing IEnumerable Interface and Understanding yield Keyword - Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474678/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Implementing-IEnumerable-I)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest method is just to enumerate over the `offers` property, like this:

```
SearchResultOffer searchResults = ...
foreach(var result in searchResults.offers)
{
    ...
}
```

But to be able to enumerate over an `SearchResultOffer` itself, you'll have to implement the `IEnumerable` interface:

```
public class SearchResultOffer : IEnumerable<SearchResultOffer1>
{
    public SearchResultOffer1[] offers { get; set; }

    // Generic version for IEnumerable<T>
    public IEnumerator<SearchResultOffer1> GetEnumerator() 
    {
        return offers.Cast<SearchResultOffer1>().GetEnumerator();
    }

    // Non-generic version for IEnumerable
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator(); // calls the generic version
    }
}
```

And then you can do this:

```
SearchResultOffer searchResults = ...
foreach(var result in searchResults)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the help.

I have added a new class to the project and added the public class SearchResultOffer but I get 4 errors:

Ambiguity between 'Taxi.Model.SearchResultOffer.offers' and 'CabForce.Model.SearchResultOffer.offers'

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.IEnumerator' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<Taxi.Model.SearchResultOffer1>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: @TrevorDaniel I believe the first error is due to namespace collisions -- you have two classes with the same name in different namespaces and in a third class you're trying to reference both. To fix that you'd have to either use fully [qualified type names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s(v=vs.110).aspx) or a [`using`-alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @TrevorDaniel The second error was my fault. I had forgotten that arrays do not implement `IEnumerable<T>`, just `IEnumerable`. See my updated answer for the fix.

Comment: Just wanted to fix a common misconception. 
In order to enumerate you don't need the class you are trying to enumerate to implement IEnumerable, you just need it to contain a public method: IEnumerator GetEnumerator().

IEnumerable interface just help with enforcing that.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code you have provided, it looks like the `SearchResult` class is really a single instance of the underlying entity, and not a *collection* as such. You may want to declare a `List<SearchResult>` to store all your results and then use `foreach` on that list.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerable` to support foreach.